# Does $PWD always equal $(realpath .)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Given

- A modern Linux/UNIX/OSX (w/ `realpath`)
- `bash` 4+ (even on OSX)

Is

```
"$PWD" == "$(realpath .)"
```

Always true?

Comment: have you even trivially tested this with a symlinked directory to get the answer you're looking for?

Comment: `PWD` is not write-protected...

Comment: Even if you assume PWD is not changed, @Petesh has the right answer. Still this question gets upvotes maybe make this an actual answer??

Comment: @Petesh As they say on Wikipedia, "Assume Good Faith" - just because it's obvious to *you* that a symlinked directory is the case that will differ, doesn't mean that it's obvious to the person answering the question. Why not instead post an answer saying "no, because a symlinked directory will behave this way".

Comment: @IMSoP do they say good faith on SO?? I assume good posts do research beforehand!? Anyway its interesting question because i didn't think about it until now

Comment: @PythonNut I think your condition is not right btw in unix/bash you must write `[ "$PWD" == "$(realpath .)" ]` i.e. brackets are not optional

Comment: @Brandin No, but I think it's a reasonable philosophy for any online forum. People here can be too quick to assume that because an answer is obvious to them, it's common sense to everyone.

Comment: Not on my system: `realpath: command not found`

Comment: @KeithThompson then your system is not one \w `realpath` as specified in the OP.

Comment: @PythonNut: Right. (It isn't installed by default on Linux Mint. I've installed it now.) I hadn't noticed the explicit qualification in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's pretty easy to test that this is not always the case.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/realdir
$ cd /tmp/realdir
$ echo $PWD
/tmp/realdir
$ ln -s realdir /tmp/fakedir
$ cd /tmp/fakedir
$ echo $PWD
/tmp/fakedir
$ realpath .
/tmp/realdir
```

so no, `$PWD` is not always the same as `$(realpath .)`.

The [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables) indicates that the `PWD` variable is set by the built-in `cd` command. the default [behaviour of cd](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) is:

> symbolic links are followed by default or with the -L option

This means that if you cd into a symlink the variable gets resolved relative to the symlink, not relative to the physical path. You can change this behavior for a `cd` command by using the `-P` option. This will cause it to report the physical directory in the `PWD` variable:

```
$ cd -P /tmp/fakedir
$ echo $PWD
/tmp/realdir
```

You can change the default behavior of bash using the `-P` option:

```
$ set -P
$ cd /tmp/fakedir
$ echo $PWD
/tmp/realdir
$ set +P
$ cd /tmp/fakedir
$ echo $PWD
/tmp/fakedir
```

This is of course notwithstanding the fact that you can assign anything you want to the `PWD` variable after performing a `cd` and it takes that value:

```
$ cd /tmp/fakedir
$ PWD=/i/love/cake
$ echo $PWD
/i/love/cake
```

but that's not really what you were asking.

Comment: Wow. Duh. Sorry, you guys were right, I know about symlinks, but for some reason, never thought you could `cd` into a symlink and leave it unresolved. (I run `zsh` normally and have `chase_links` set)

Comment: This answer would be better if you quote bash manual and realpath(1). Additionally, right now you consider only one case that cause $PWD != `realpath .`. @Pumbaa80 mentioned the other important way in which $PWD is not same as `realpath .`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily the case even when symbolic links are not used and `PWD` is not set by the user:

```
vinc17@xvii:~$ mkdir my_dir
vinc17@xvii:~$ cd my_dir
vinc17@xvii:~/my_dir$ rmdir ../my_dir
vinc17@xvii:~/my_dir$ echo $PWD
/home/vinc17/my_dir
vinc17@xvii:~/my_dir$ realpath .
.: No such file or directory
```

Note that under zsh, `${${:-.}:A}` still gives the same answer as `$PWD` (the `zshexpn(1)` man page says about the A modifier: "Note that the transformation takes place even if the file or any intervening directories do not exist.").

Note that however, `$PWD` contains obsolete information. Using it may be a bad idea if some other process can remove the directory. Consider the following script:

```
rm -rf my_dir
mkdir my_dir
cd my_dir
echo 1 > file
cat $PWD/file
rm -r ../my_dir
mkdir ../my_dir
echo 2 > ../my_dir/file
cat ./file
cat $PWD/file
rm -r ../my_dir
```

It will output:

```
1
cat: ./file: No such file or directory
2
```

i.e. `$PWD/file` has changed.