# Does $PWD always equal ${${:-.}:A}

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

Given

- A modern Linux/UNIX/OSX
- `zsh` 5+
- `setopt chase_links`
- `PWD` has not been set abnormally

Is

```
[[ "$PWD" == "${${:-.}:A}" ]]
```

Always true?

Comment: I can't help wondering if there's a way of combining this with [the realpath question you just asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223466/does-pwd-always-equal-realpath). I realise they're about different tools, but the underlying question seems to be "what is `$PWD`, and how does it relate to other ways of calculating the current path?"

Comment: I'm also wondering if both would fit better on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I originally had them as one question, but I've been told that separate questions should remain separate. `zsh` has control of `$PWD` and it may not be the same as the way `bash` handles `$PWD`.

Comment: upvoted for the crazy line noise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not always true:

```
xvii:~> ls -l foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vinc17 vinc17 10 2014-07-05 01:12:06 foo -> bar/subdir/
xvii:~> bash
vinc17@xvii:~$ cd foo
vinc17@xvii:~/foo$ pwd
/home/vinc17/foo
vinc17@xvii:~/foo$ zsh -f
xvii% echo $PWD
/home/vinc17/foo
xvii% setopt chase_links
xvii% echo $PWD
/home/vinc17/foo
xvii% echo "${${:-.}:A}"
/home/vinc17/bar/subdir
xvii% pwd
/home/vinc17/bar/subdir
```

But if zsh is started in a current working directory that has no symlink segments, then the current working directory will never have symlink segments either after a `cd` (or equivalent), and `..` or `.` in the current working directory are not possible either since they are resolved when changing the directory, so that `$PWD` and `${${:-.}:A}` should be equivalent if the directory still exists (see below).

In the above example, after a `cd .`, zsh updates `$PWD` to `/home/vinc17/bar/subdir`. However, a `cd .` doesn't make both forms equivalent in all cases:

```
xvii% mkdir my_dir
xvii% cd my_dir
xvii% rmdir ../my_dir
xvii% echo $PWD
/home/vinc17/my_dir
xvii% echo "${${:-.}:A}"
/home/vinc17/my_dir
xvii% pwd
/home/vinc17/my_dir
xvii% cd .
xvii% echo $PWD
/home/vinc17/my_dir
xvii% echo "${${:-.}:A}"

xvii% pwd
.
xvii% echo "$(realpath .)"
.: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Wow! That's a pretty obscure different, I'm glad you found it. So if I do `cd .` in `.zshrc` they're always the same?

Comment: @PythonNut No, after a `cd .`, they're not necessarily the same. I've corrected and completed my answer. You can even see that 4 forms to try to output the real path of the current working directory yield 4 different outputs.